# Xeon E5-2697 v2 won't work on my C602 (LGA2011) motherboard? I already spent $2500 and can't return it

Tags: cpu

According to specs, the new CPU should work with the motherboard and socket. The indicator on the motherboard shows 00 which means CPU won't even start booting up. 
BIOS is up-to-date.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[That CPU isn't on the chipset's compatibility list](http://ark.intel.com/products/63984/Intel-BD82C602-PCH#@compatibility)